# Number of tosses probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been trying to solve the following task, and there is something unclear. It goes like this: A person tosses a symmetric coin until both head and tail have appeared at least twice. Determine the probability function of the number of tosses.

Solution: $P(X=k)$=$\frac{num.of.favorable}{num.of. possible}$=$\frac{2(k-1)}{2^k}$

I understand how $2^k$ is obtained, but I don't fully understand $2(k-1)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good paths that end in $H$ must be of the form $T^aHT^bH$ where $a,b$ are non-negative integers that sum to $k-2$.  There are $k-1$ such.  Similarly, there are $k-1$ good paths that end in $T$.